# How do I rectify "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" error in a programmatically set up constraints animation?

Tags: swift

I have tried to animate the constraints of a UIView, and this is resulting in the aforementioned error for a reason I can't quite fathom.

My relevant code set up is as follows:

```
var FourTop: NSLayoutConstraint!

FourTop = containerFour.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerTwo.bottomAnchor)

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

 NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

containerFour.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
containerFour.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.285),
containerFour.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),    
FourTop,

])
```

And here is the code where I try to animate the FourTop constraint:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, animations: {
        self.containerTwo.alpha = 0
    }) { finished in
        self.FourTop = self.containerFour.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 115)
        self.FourTop.isActive = true
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.75, delay: 0.25, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.4, initialSpringVelocity: 0.9, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
```

The error that I get is fairly confusing and I'm unable to figure out which view the error is trying to specify since it gives each UIElement a weird name. The error is:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002b6c0a0 UIView:0x7f842fe077b0.height == 0.285*UIView:0x7f842fc0fd60.height   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002b6c690 UIView:0x7f842fe077b0.top == UILayoutGuide:0x600003154540'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.top   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002b6c730 V:[UIView:0x7f842fe077b0]-(0)-[UIView:0x7f842fe09020]   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002b6f0c0 UIView:0x7f842fe09020.top == UILayoutGuide:0x600003154540'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.top + 115   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002b6dfe0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIView:0x7f842fc0fd60.height == 896   (active)>"
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002b6c730 V:[UIView:0x7f842fe077b0]-(0)-[UIView:0x7f842fe09020     (active)>
```

My attempts to rectify this have been to try and delete some constraints and re-try, and to try and figure out which constraint is at fault, but in vain.

Can somebody guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to deactivate the old top constraint before adding the new one:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, animations: {
    self.containerTwo.alpha = 0
}) { finished in
    self.FourTop.isActive = false  // remove old constraint first
    self.FourTop = self.containerFour.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 115)
    self.FourTop.isActive = true
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.75, delay: 0.25, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.4, initialSpringVelocity: 0.9, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```